# Comparing "point", "pointer" and "tip"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Could anyone please tell me what is the difference between the synonymous words "[point](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/point)", "[pointer](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/pointer)" and "[tip](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/tip)"?

According to the dictionary definitions, they are so close in meaning that I am unable to distinguish between them!

I was wondering if there is any difference between the sentences below:

**Example:**

> - **1.** He **made** some interesting **points** in his speech about the way we should  raise our children properly.
> - **2.** He **gave** some interesting **pointers** in his speech about the way we should  raise our children properly.
> - **3.** He **gave** some interesting **tips** in his speech about the way we should  raise our children properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Making a point" is just saying something meaningful; it is the basic unit we break discourse down into. It is not the same as "giving a tip," which is a piece of advice. A pointer is similar to a tip, but to me it suggests active feedback and critique, not just general advice (that could be argued on though).

2 sounds a bit odd to me in this context. 3 would be appropriate if the speaker is advocating certain methods, while 1 would make sense in almost any case (such as if he's being more analytical about parenting in general without necessarily giving advice). With the word "should," it sounds like 3 is most likely the right choice here.

Comment: Thank you, but what if the speaker does not provide the  audience with detailed information and just mentions the topics? For instance, you should never raise your voice to your child. - You'd better always be a friend to your child rather that jus playing a mother or a father role. - You have to always tell them the truth, but not necessarily all the truth, etc. As you see, these pieces of advice are just bullet points and not detailed and analytical information.

Comment: @A-friend Yeah, those sound like tips. They are also points, just not very detailed ones.